# How can I call the following void function with double parameters?

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, function-definition, function-call

This is what I have currently, and I have no idea what to do to make it run:

```
void avg_sum(double a[], int n, double *avg, double *sum) {   
    int i;
    *sum = 0.0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        *sum += a[i];

    *avg = *sum / n; 
}

int main () {
    int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int avg = 3;
    int sum = 2;

    avg_sum(array, 5, avg, sum);
}
```

I tried manipulating the arguments for running the function, but I can't figure out how to make it work. It can be simple, I just have to write a program to test the `avg_sum` function. That portion must remain the same.

Comment: You can't call this function with `int` variables.

Comment: A good compiler will tell you in its error messages what arguments you pass, and what arguments it expects. What does your compiler say? What do *you* think about the messages the compiler gives you?

Comment: Your function doesn't take parameters of type `double`. It takes an array of them and pointers to them.  Assuming `n` is meant to be the size of the array `a`, it should be of type `size_t`.

Comment: If you're not getting a boatload of warnings, turn up your warnings and [treat them as errors](https://godbolt.org/z/ahraKx7da), because that is exactly what they are. If you *are* getting warnings, don't ignore them, and the best way to do that is, again, treat them as errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want this:

```
int main () {
    double array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};  // use double
    double avg = 3;
    double sum = 2;

    avg_sum(array, 5, &avg, &sum);      // call with &
}
```

- `avg_sum` operates on `double`s, therefore you need to provide doubles.
- parametrers 3 and 4 must be *pointers* to double, therefore you need to use the address operator `&`.

All this is covered in the first chapters of your beginner's C txt book.

Answer (score 1):

For starters these initializations

```
int avg = 3;
int sum = 2;
```

does not make a sense.

At least it will be more meaningfully to initialize these variables by zero

```
int avg = 0;
int sum = 0;
```

The function `avg_sum` expects that the third and fourth arguments will be accepted by reference through pointers to them.

```
void avg_sum(double a[], int n, double *avg, double *sum) {
```

So the function must be called like

```
avg_sum(array, 5, &avg, &sum);
```

Also the function expects that the first, third and fourth arguments declared with the type specifier `double`  but you are passing arguments declared with the type specifier `int`.

The function itself should be declared and defined the following way

```
void avg_sum( const int a[], size_t n, double *avg,  int *sum ) 
{   
    *sum = 0;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        *sum += a[i];
    }

    *avg = n == 0 ? 0.0 : *sum / n; 
}
```

So within main the variables `avg` and `sum` have to be declared like

```
double avg = 0.0;
int sum = 0;
```

Also after the call of the function

```
avg_sum(array, 5, &avg, &sum);
```

it seems you should output the obtained values like for example

```
printf( "sum = %d, average = %.2f\n", sum, avg );
```